# removeAll function removes more than expected

Tags: groovy, difference

I have the following functionality that I’ve seen people use in order to get
the differences between two lists.

Note: this is not the actual code but a representation of what I have, in actuality each number can be replaced by an object with properties.

```
def listA = [1,2,3,4,5]
def listB = [1,2,3,6,7]

def common = listA.intersect(listB)//expected: [1,2,3], actual: same
def all = listA.plus(listB)//expected: [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7], actual: same
all.removeAll(common)//expected: [4,5,6,7], actual: [6,7]
```

Comment: Running above code (Groovy 4.0.18), gives me `[4,5,6,7]` -- the expected for `all`. Could you please add the Groovy version you are using and ideally how you determined the `actual`?  With `removeAll` the original container is modified, so maybe you have a different problem not shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified,

```
def big = [1, 1, 2, 3]
def small = [1, 2]
```

The code

```
big.removeAll(small)
```

removes *all matching elements*. Both `1` and `1` from `big` match `1` from `small`, so they are both removed, for the result `[3]`. What you probably want is

```
small.each { big.removeElement(it) }
```

where for each element of `small` a *single matching element* of `big` is removed, for the result `[1, 3]`.

See [docs](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html).

Answer (score 0):

You want the [Symmetric
difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) between
your two sets.

[Groovy 5](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-5.0.html) will have the `^` operator(-overload) for this:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3] as Set 
var b = [2, 3, 4] as Set
assert (a ^ b) == [1, 4] as Set
```

But you can do this now now manually, by removing the *intersection* from
the *union*.

```
def listA = [1,2,3,4,5].toSet()
def listB = [1,2,3,6,7].toSet()

def union = listA + listB
def intersection = listA.intersect(listB)

def symmetricDifference = union - intersection

println(symmetricDifference) // → [4, 5, 6, 7]
```